# Je n'arrive pas a mettre mon bot en ligne

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I really need help and an answer would be pretty cool.

I'm trying to create my discord bot, and for that I installed discord.py, but it really doesn't want to work, I don't understand.

With each problem solved, a new one appears.
I attach here my screens of my errors.

Help me please !
here is my script
voici mon script

```
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.bot (command_prefix = "!")

@bot.event 
async def on_ready():
    print("on ready !")

bot.run("----")
```

and here is the error:

PS C:\Users\Mathis> & C:/Users/Mathis/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/python.exe "c:/Users/Mathis/Documents/bot python/main.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Users\Mathis\Documents\bot python\main.py", line 4, in 
bot = commands.bot (command_prefix = "!")
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Comment: Please edit and write in English, as [Stack Overflow is an English only site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/do-posts-have-to-be-in-english-on-stack-exchange).

Answer (score 0):

First you need to import the Discord module:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
```

You also need to set your bot permissions under [Discord Developers - Applications](https://discord.com/developers/applications/) and declare your intentions in your code:

`intent = discord.Intents.all()`

So, your code would look something like this:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

intent = discord.Intents.all()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "!", intents = intent)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Ready!")

bot.run('Token here')
```

Your bot will work fine like this.

Answer (score -1):

> in bot = commands.bot (command_prefix = "!") TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

It's **B**ot with an uppercase `B`.

Comment: Please don't post an answer for typos. It's a close reason.